# Biblatex 'origlanguage' field and output customization

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I need to specify original language and the translator in the bibliography list, but it spits out a grammatically incorrect 
(Correct me if I have been a victim of Muphry's laws):

> Trans. from the German by ...

So how can I get rid of the word 'the' in the Bibliography? I saw it in brackets in the biblatex manual and was wondering, what do the brackets mean.

As usual, minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
     style=authoryear,
     citestyle=apa,
     backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Alpha},
    origlanguage = {german},
    translator = {Buthor, B.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{MWE}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

This is the only citation \parencite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of "the" is typical in English bibliographies. Presumably this is a shortening of the phrase "translated from the `<language>` original". To redefine the strings add the following to your preamble.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  fromamerican     = {from American},
  frombrazilian    = {from Brazilian},
  fromcroatian     = {from Croatian},
  fromdanish       = {from Danish},
  fromdutch        = {from Dutch},
  fromenglish      = {from English},
  fromfinnish      = {from Finnish},
  fromfrench       = {from French},
  fromgerman       = {from German},
  fromgreek        = {from Greek},
  fromitalian      = {from Italian},
  fromlatin        = {from Latin},
  fromnorwegian    = {from Norwegian},
  fromportuguese   = {from Portuguese},
  fromrussian      = {from Russian},
  fromspanish      = {from Spanish},
  fromswedish      = {from Swedish},
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was banging my head against the wall for a while and could not think why biblatex would want to put 'the' there.