# Using multiple language fields in a bbliography (English / Korean)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, languages, polyglossia

This is a clarification of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503585/dividing-biblatex-bibliography-by-language-using-origlanguage) and **uses that MWE**. The MWE *origtitle*, *origpublisher* etc fields aren't fully populated yet.

```
@article{Ka91, 
     origtitle = {투자은행이 IPO의 가격형성에 미치는 영향에 관한 실증분석},
     origpublisher = {재무관리연구}
     title = {An Empirical Study on ...},
     publisher = {The Korean Journal of Financial Management}
     origlanguage = {Korean},
}
```

I can now separate my Bibliographies into English and Korean sections.

I'd now like to print the English text in the English Bibl'ies and the Korean text in the Korean Bibl'y. (Items 1 and 2 in the picture). A third possibility is a combined Bibliography as shown in Item 3. This was copied from an article in [Asian Review of Financial Research](https://www.slideshare.net/EndiNugroho/24-206) page 34 or thereabouts.

If it's simpler I can do without localising "Vol.", "No." etc.

[image: sample bibliographiesin English, Korean and combined]

Edit to add a more comprehensive Korean MWE as requested by Moewe. The text is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_mixed_script) and pasted in. It must be compiled with xelatex, pdflatex doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{CJKutf8} 
\usepackage{xeCJK}  
\setCJKmainfont[Mapping=Jamo]{UnGungseo.ttf}
\setCJKsansfont{UnGungseo.ttf}
\setCJKmonofont{gulim.ttf}


\begin{document}
\section*{Korean Mixed Script}

Korean mixed script, known in Korean as hanja honyong (Korean: 한자혼용; Hanja: 漢字混用), Hanja-seokkeosseugi (漢字섞어쓰기, 한자섞어쓰기), 'Chinese character mixed usage,' or gukhanmun honyong (국한문혼용; 國漢文混用), 'national Sino-Korean mixed usage,' is a form of writing the Korean language that uses a mixture of the Korean alphabet or hangul (한글) and hanja (漢字, 한자), the Korean name for Chinese characters. The distribution on how to write words usually follows that all native Korean words, including grammatical endings, particles and honorific markers are generally written in hangul and never in hanja. Sino-Korean vocabulary or hanja-eo (한자어; 漢字語), either words borrowed from Chinese or created from Sino-Korean roots, were generally always written in hanja although very rare or complex characters were often substituted with hangul. Although the Korean alphabet was introduced and taught to people beginning in 1446, most literature until the early twentieth century was written in literary Chinese known as hanmun (한문; 漢文). 

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Chinese Original & 有朋自遠方來 不亦樂乎  \\ \hline
1590 translation by Yi Yulgok  & 朋이 遠方으로브터 오리이시면 樂흡디 아니랴  \\
Hangul-only transcription of 1590 translation & 붕이 원방으로브터 오리이시면 낙흡디 아니랴  \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Modern Korean gloss} & 벗(동문-혹은 뜻을 같이 하는 이)이 있  \\
   & 멀리서부터 사방에서   \\
   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}어 오니 혹은 먼 곳에서 오니 \\ 또한 즐겁지 아니한가?\end{tabular} \\
English translation  & Having oneself friends arriving from distant regions, \\ &  is that not happiness? \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Korean wiki side by side with LaTex]

Comment: You mention being able to typeset CJK using `\setCJKmainfont` in the comments to the other question. I'm not very familiar with CJK typesetting, so I would *really* appreciate it if you could add an MWE based on the MWE from the other question to this question here that sets up stuff for Korean in the main text with `\setCJKmainfont` and friends.

Comment: Sorry my MWE was too minimal. I'm not familiar with CKJ and this only needs to work with Korean: